# Cofirm box is not working in javascript validation

Tags: javascript

I am working on a form with java script validation.I have a problem with the validation.The confirm box is not working at a particular instance. My code is

```
if((frm_update_announcement.sublink[0].checked == true)) {
    if((document.getElementById('captionurl').value.trim()=="") && document.getElementById("captionfile").files.length == 0 ) ) {   
        if (document.getElementById('olddocument').value.trim()=="") {
            alert("Enter a url/upload a file");
            document.getElementById('captionurl').focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if((frm_update_announcement.sublink[1].checked == true)) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById('attachment_caption' + i).value.trim()!="") {
            if ((document.getElementById('url'+i).value.trim()=="") && (document.getElementById("document"+i).files.length == 0 ) ) {
                alert("Add url/file with caption");
                document.getElementById('url'+i).focus();
                return false;   
            }                             
        }
    }         
}
if(confirm("Do you want to update the announcement") == true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

My HTML is

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="sublink" id="id_radio2" value="0" <?php if($announcements_details['detail_type']=="0") echo' checked="checked"'?> >&nbsp;Add attachment to title</input>
</label>
<div class="col-md-4">      
<label> 
    <input type="radio" name="sublink" id="id_radio1"  value="1" <?php if($announcements_details['detail_type']=="1") echo' checked="checked"'?> >&nbsp;Add new sublinks</input>
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">      
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="sublink" id="id_radio3" value="2" <?php if($announcements_details['detail_type']=="2") echo' checked="checked"'?>>&nbsp;None
</label>
```

When the condition `frm_update_announcement.sublink[1].checked` becomes true, the confirm box is not showing up. That's the problem. But the alert box inside that function is showing correctly.

Comment: `if(confirm("Do you want to update the announcement"))`

Comment: @Azola-it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
var txt;
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Comment: My problem is with the if ( ( frm_update_announcement.sublink[1].checked == true )).if i remove that condition it works nicely

Comment: what is this  `frm_update_announcement.sublink[1].checked`

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error inside your first if statement.

replace below code with your first if statement.

```
 if ( ( frm_update_announcement.sublink[0].checked == true )){
        if ((document.getElementById('captionurl').value.trim()=="" )  && (document.getElementById("captionfile").files.length == 0) )
            {  
                if (document.getElementById('olddocument').value.trim()=="")
                 {
                    alert("Enter a url/upload a file");
                    document.getElementById('captionurl').focus();
                    return false;
                }
             }

}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks-Doesn't work..I have something mistake inside the condition ( ( frm_update_announcement.sublink[1].checked == true ))

Comment: sorry ..nothing happened..i have found the problem is in                            **if((document.getElementById('url'+i).value.trim()=="") && (document.getElementById("document"+i).files.length == 0 ) )**